# OData V6.6.0 is not allowing $search

Tags: search, odata

I'm trying to use OData V6.6.0 $search functionality. I initially had version 5.2 which I updated to version 6.6.0. However, I still am not able to use $search. When I use it in url

```
odata/Prescribers?$inlinecount=allpages&$top=20&$search=TEST';
```

I get this error message 'The query parameter '$search' is not supported.'

Do I need to do something else in order to add $search functionality. Btw, I'm also using EnableQuery in my Controller like this.

```
    [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = System.Web.Http.OData.Query.AllowedQueryOptions.All)]

 public IQueryable<ContactList> Get()
        {
            return dbContext.ContactsList.AsQueryable();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. If substringof is used in the filter then it returns the records of value containing the string. I used $filter with 'or' operator to check multiple columns.

```
'&$filter=substringof(\'' + key + '\', NPI)' +
  'or substringof(\'' + key + '\', Zip)' +                        
  'or substringof(\'' + key + '\', PrescriberName)';
```

This displayed all the records that contains the string in the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is kind of old, I wanted to give you my take of an implementation of a "$search to $filter" mapping based on an AllowSearchAttribute on the model. It is implemented as an attribute derived from `EnableQueryAttribute`. The "magic" is to take the `$search` part of the query, convert it to a `$filter` clause, and remove it from the parameters before further processing is done by the infrastructure. This is achieved by replacing `request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.RequestQueryNameValuePairsKey]` with a changed array. This is the cache, from which later processing will fetch the query fields (see `request.GetQueryNameValuePairs`).

```
public class EnableQueryWithSearchAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public Type ModelType { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var request = actionExecutedContext.Request;
        var query = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().ToList();
        var searchParam = query.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == "$search");
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchParam.Key))
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchParam.Value))
            {
                string filterString = null;
                var filter = query.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == "$filter");
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Key))
                {
                    filterString = filter.Value;
                }

                var odataSearchValue = searchParam.Value.Replace("'", "''");
                var props = this.ModelType
                    .GetProperties()
                    .Where(pi => pi.GetCustomAttribute<AllowSearchAttribute>() != null)
                    .Select(pi => pi.Name)
                    .ToList();

                if (props.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterString))
                    {
                        filterString = "(" + filterString + ") and ";
                    }

                    filterString += "(contains(" +
                                    String.Join(", '" + odataSearchValue + "') or contains(", props) + ", '" +
                                    odataSearchValue + "'))";
                }

                request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.RequestQueryNameValuePairsKey] =
                    query.Where(q => q.Key != "$search" && q.Key != "$filter").Concat(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("$filter", filterString) }).ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.RequestQueryNameValuePairsKey] =
                    query.Where(q => q.Key != "$search").ToArray();
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

The AllowSearchAttribute is a descriptive attribute with no extra info.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class AllowSearchAttribute : Attribute { }
```

On the model class, you can specify which properties should be searched, by applying the `[AllowSearch]` attribute to the desired properties. In the example, only `Title` and `Description` will be searched:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [AllowSearch]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [AllowSearch]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SomethingNotSearchable { get; set; }
}
```

And on the method where you typically apply the `[EnableQuery]` attribute, you will use the derived one and specify the model type:

```
[EnableQueryWithSearch(EnsureStableOrdering = true, ModelType = typeof(MyModel))]
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<MyModel> Get()
{
    // your code here.
}
```

You can now call your OData endpoint with a $search parameter, which will be mapped to a corresponding $filter parameter internally. The current implementation always uses a `contains(...)` operation, but you could easily enhance the implementation with custom [AllowSearch] parameters, which will issue other operations.

Hope this helps someone. I couldn't find any other implementation of this sort anywhere, so I thought I'd share.

Answer (score 0):

WebApi currently doesn't support $search. In order to support it, you can start from here https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Query/ODataQueryOptions.cs to simulate other query options, and then reference you private built dll.

Comment: So what you're saying is just OData supporting $search is not enough, WebAPI also needs to support it? I'm sorry if I'm being ignorant, I'm learning C# and backbone as I go along. So, is there a way to make $filter have SQL "LIKE" functionality?

Comment: I think yes, WebApi will support $search in future. and there is a function named "contains" that acts similar with the SQL "LIKE", for example, $filter=contains(Name,'i'). Just try it: http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Products?$filter=contains(Name,%27i%27)